# Event delegates disappear after being added in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, linq, events

I am trying to add event delegates to the objects I have got in a list. In the following example, I want to add the `dinosaur_Jumped` delegate whenever an object fires the associated event. I am adding them in a `foreach` loop, but somehow they disappear straight after that.

```
class MyViewModel
{
    MyViewModel(List<Dinosaur> dinosaurs)
    {
        // This works and creates the ViewModel the way I expect it to:
        m_dinosaurs = dinosaurs.Select( x => new DinosaurViewModel(x) );

        foreach (DinosaurViewModel dino in m_dinosaurs)
        {
            // This works within the scope of the loop
            dino.Jumped += dinosaur_Jumped;
        }

        // But now all my Jumped delegates are suddenly all gone
    }

    void dinosaur_Jumped(object sender, JumpingEventArgs e)
    {
        // This never gets called, even when the events do fire:
        Console.WriteLine("A dinosaur jumped");
    }

    private IEnumerable<DinosaurViewModel> m_dinosaurs;
}
```

I am presuming it has something to do with incorrect scope/closures or something; adding a delegate to a variable (in this case `dino`) that goes out of scope immediately, but I don't know how else I could this. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: You may want to update your code sample with how you are checking the `Jumped` delegates, are you using a subsequent `foreach` loop?

Answer (score 3):

As I cannot see how you are checking your `Jumped` delegates, I will assume you are performing a subsequent iteration of `m_dinosaurs`.

Because `Select` is lazy, any subsequent iterations will result in different `DinosaurViewModel` instances being created, this means you are inspecting different instances to those which have had the event handler added.

A solution to this is to materialize the collection, e.g.

```
m_dinosaurs = dinosaurs.Select( x => new DinosaurViewModel(x) ).ToList();
```

**Possible Garbage Collection**

A less likely but possible situation results from the garbage collector, your `Select` statement will create a new `DinosaurViewModel` for each iteration, when you iterate `m_dinosaurs` and add the event handler the newly created `DinosaurViewModel` becomes eligible for garbage collection as there is nothing keeping a reference to it.

The solution is to ensure you keep a reference to each created `DinosaurViewModel`, the same solution as above will be sufficient as the `.ToList()` call will ensure a reference to each created `DinosaurViewModel` is retained, this means they are no longer eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: This was my first thought this as well, but that's wrong.  The linq is evaluated immediately in the next `foreach` statement.  It's not necessary to call `ToList` nor will doing so have any impact.

Comment: @PhilipPittle After each iteration of the `foreach` loop there is nothing keeping a reference to the newly created `DinosaurViewModel`, the `.ToList()` ensures the view-models are materialized and a reference retained.

Comment: @PhilipPittle What you can try is a simple `var e = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }.Select(i => { Console.WriteLine(i); return i; }); foreach (var i in e) { /* do nothing */ } foreach (var i in e) { /* do nothing again */ }`. You'll see that the numbers are printed twice.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think garbage collection matters here. It doesn't matter whether the first batch of `DinosaurViewModel` objects get GC-ed: the problem is simply that the second batch doesn't have any event subscribers. That's a problem even if the first batch is still around.

Comment: @hvd ah yes, you are correct, the subsequent evaluation will result in different view-model instances, I'll leave my answer here however, as I have been bitten by deferred LINQ and the GC before!

Answer (score 2):

`Enumerable.Select` is lazy. Very lazy. So lazy, in fact, that it completely disregards any output you've already seen from it. When you iterate over `m_dinosaurs` a second time, you get a completely fresh batch of `DinosaurModel` objects.

You may use `dinosaurs.ConvertAll( x => new DinosaurViewModel(x) )` instead, to store the models in a list.